# Property 'row' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts(2339)

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, element-plus, volar

[image]

When i update Volar to 1.4.4,element-plus el-table use slot,ts error.

if use `<template #default="scope: any"></template>` can solve the problem,but i wanna use `<template #default="{ row }"></template>`

Comment: Are you setting a `:row` prop on the slot? Can you add code for `el-table-column`?

Comment: I just copy the official document code, I don't found how to setting :row